# Using FFT to compute sumproduct of two 2D arrays

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, signal-processing, fftw

I am doing program to remove noise from image, in it, i need to compute a lot of sums of pointwise multiplications, right now, i do it through direct approach and it takes huge computation cost:

```
int ret=0, arr1[n][n].arr2[n][n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) for (int j=0;j<n;j++) ret+=arr1[i][j]*arr2[i][j];
```

I was told, that to compute this convolution between two arrays, i should do this (
[more details here here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/how-one-apply-correctly-fft-in-image-denoising) ) :

1. Calculate the DFT of array 1 (via FFT).
2. Calculate the DFT of array 2 (via FFT).
3. Multiply the two DFTs element-wise. It should be a complex multiplication.
4. Calculate the inverse DFT (via FFT) of the multiplied DFTs. That'll be your convolution result.

It seems, that algorithmic part is more or less clear, but i came to a new problem:

I selected fftw for this task, but after a long time, spent by reading it's docs, i still don't see any function for 2D inverse fft which returns not 2D array, but a single value akin to direct approach, not whole 2D array, what am i missing?

Comment: You''re not doing a convolution - you're just doing a product - so FFT-based convolution is not going to help you. If you need more performance consider SIMD or GPGPU.

Comment: thanks, for your answer, here i posted minimum theoretical details, just don't know, how to use fftw, but it is in fact convolution, each of array is centered around pixel, all the theory is here - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/how-one-apply-correctly-fft-in-image-denoising

Comment: OK - you should probably delete the question here on SO then, as all your questions seem to have been answered already on DSP.SE.

Comment: algorithnic part yes, it was answered and cleared most of doubts, but the problem here is practical (that's why no theory, only how to compute circular convolution)- in fftw library inverse fft nethods return 2D array and not a single value as i want, i don't know, what to look

Comment: I think your problem is that you still don't completely understand the *algorithm*. Convolution of two 2D images will return a 2D image. FFT and inverse FFT have the same number of input and output points. Looking at the answers and comments on DSP.SE it looks like all the information is there - you just need to go back and re-read it carefully so that you fully understand the algorithm. Implementation should then be straightforward.